# Display Object Vertices in UV Editor

Tags: modeling

As you can see in the uv editor below, I am in edit mode but I cannot see the vertices of my object. I have selected it in object mode too. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're following the anvil tutorial, you have two anvils at this point.  Are you sure you're editing the right one, and that the 2nd one isn't hiding it?  What do you see if you go to wire display mode in the 3D viewport on the right?

Comment: I have selected all the vertices of the anvil but it is still not showing in edit mode
https://i.imgur.com/eziaC6w.png

Comment: I am editing the right one too

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the edit window in wireframe mode or share your blend file ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  If you're editing the right one, then it is being obscured by the one you can see in the edit window, which does not appear to be selected or in edit mode.

Comment: @MartyFouts I have shared the blend file

Comment: The mistake was mine.  You do have the correct anvil but you've accidentally turned overlays off.  I'll write an answer explaining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll the header in the edit window so that the right side set of buttons is showing, you'll find this:

[image: Overlays disabled]

The third button from the left, the closed circle behind an open circle means that you have overlays disabled.  Overlays show you things like vertices, edges, faces, and, of course selections.

Click it so that it is enabled like this:

[image: Overlays enabled]

and your vertices will appear.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry I guessed wrong the first time.